# Convert abstract type to 7 possible other types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract partial class AsyncResult
{
}
```

And 7 other classes that inherit from it(here are only 2 for reference):

```
public partial class AsyncSearchResult : AsyncResult
{
    private SearchResult searchResultField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com", Order=0)]
    public SearchResult searchResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.searchResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.searchResultField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class AsyncGetListResult : AsyncResult
{
    private ReadResponseList readResponseListField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public ReadResponseList readResponseList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.readResponseListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.readResponseListField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method that returns the abstract type and I need to cast it to one of the specific types in order to access the desired property.

I can't find a way to cast it at compile time without writing 7 ifs for each case and duplicate the code a lot.

Appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: why should you convert parent to child? i think it is a design pattern problem...

Comment: Visitor pattern may be helpful

Comment: Why do you have a memberless abstract class to begin with is what I'd like to know. If none of the response types shares any common members I don't think it makes any sense for them to inherit the same base class.

Comment: @Crono It's a lot clearer to pass an `AsyncResult` object, than to pass `object`. C# lacks discriminated unions, and the best alternative is a class hierarchy

Comment: I can't really say anything about the design pattern. This is an auto-generated file using Svcutil

Comment: @canton7 I agree with you about passing `object`, but really I don't think a method that has to check out any of seven possible derived types of an instance feels right either. ‍♂️

Comment: @Crono It makes sense in context, I think. This is fairly clearly an XML `xsd:choice`: the element at a particular point in the document can be one of a set number of types. When you're parsing the document, you don't know what you're going to find there.

Comment: @S.Bob Is this about Wcf of some sort? Or SOAP in general?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, it was generated using WCF. The method is used to search a record by ID, the response can be any of those 7 types :(

Comment: Then it's even worse. If the contract changes, your App may encounter "unknown" types ... I hope, it's versioned properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using the visitor pattern for this:

```
public interface IAsyncResultVisitor
{
    void Accept(AsyncSearchResult searchResult);
    void Accept(AsyncGetListResult getListResult);
    // Etc...
}

public abstract partial class AsyncResult
{
    public abstract void Visit(IAsyncResultVisitor visitor);
}

public partial class AsyncSearchResult : AsyncResult
{
    // ...
    public override void Visit(IAsyncResultVisitor visitor) => visitor.Accept(this);
}
```

Then:

```
public class AsyncResultProcessor : IAsyncResultVisitor
{
    public void ProcessAsyncResult(AsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        asyncResult.Visit(this);
    }

    public void Accept(AsyncSearchResult searchResult)
    {
        // Access strongly-typed members of searchResult
    }

    public void Accept(AsyncGetListResult getListResult)
    {
        // Access strongly-typed members of getListResult
    }
}
```

---

Note that switch statements and switch expressions also help here, although they don't ensure that you've covered every single case (as the visitor pattern does):

```
switch (asyncResult)
{
    case AsyncSearchResult searchResult:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I tend to refactor those switch-Statements _to_ double-dispatch visitor ... but maybe that's a question of taste?

Comment: @Fildor It depends on circumstance. Sometimes I only care about 1 or 2 possible types, and implementing the visitor interface is too much boilerplate, so I'll refactor to a switch. Sometimes completeness is more important, and I'll refactor to visitor. Once (if!) we get DUs, and we can write a switch over a DU and get an error if it isn't complete, I'll probably move entirely away from visitor for this.

Comment: I see. - That's a rather big "if", though ... :(

Comment: They keep promising it, then deciding it's hard and punting it until the next version. I've got some hopes for C# 11

Answer (score 0):

I would've implemented visitor in different way. Problem with @canton7 implementation is that data have to know how people should work with it, but it's just plain data!

First: `AsyncResult` should have [`private protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected) constructor, so no other assemblies could "implement" this abstract class

```cs
public abstract class AsyncResult
{
    private protected AsyncResult() {}
}

public sealed class ResultOne : AsyncResult()
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
// 6 more to go
```

Make interface to match all types

```cs
public interface IAsyncResultVisitor
{
    void Visit(AsyncResult result);
    void VisitResultOne(ResultOne result);
    void VisitResultTwo(ResultTwo result);
    // 5 more to go
}
```

And create default visitor that's gonna have properties for each type containing visit strategy

```cs
public sealed class LambdaAsyncResultVisitor : IAsyncResultVisitor
{
    public Action<ResultOne> OnVisitOne { get; set; } 
    public void VisitResultOne(ResultOne result)
    {
       if (OnVisitOne is null)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
       OnVisitOne.Invoke(result);
    }
    // 6 more to go
}
```

This would allow us to use it this way

```cs
AsyncResult result = ...;

string someString = "";
new LambdaAsyncResultVisitor
{
   OnVisitOne = r => someString = r.Data,
   OnVisitTwo = r => someString = "two",
   OnVisitThree => _ =>  throw new Exception("I know that is is impossible"),
}.Visit(result);

HandleSomeString(someString);
```

This gives much more flexibility than default visitor pattern

Comment: The reasons I tend to avoid this pattern are: 1) Holy delegate allocations, Batman; 2) Nothing's forcing you to consider all cases, which means that it's basically no different to a switch statement/expression. Why write the `LambdaAsyncResultVisitor` at all when you can just write `someString = result switch { ResultOne r => r.Data, ResultTwo _ => "two", _ => throw new ... }`?

Comment: 1) Yep, there's at least 2 allocations per each lambda. 2) May be enforced with constructor, instead of properties. I think it's good because of exhaustiveness, that can't be achieved with regular switch and it's doesn't depends on knowledge of 1 person, who wrote this. Easier to maintain, harder to miss something